# How to handle ids and polymorphic associations in views if compound keys are not supported?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord

I have a Movie plan table:

```
movie_plans (id, description)
```

Each plan has items, which describe a sequence of movies and the duration in minutes:

```
movie_plan_items (id, movie_plan_id, movie_id, start_minutes, end_minutes)
```

A specific instance of that plan happens in:

```
movie_schedules (id, movie_plan_id, start_at)
```

However the schedule items can be calculated from the movie_plan_items and the schedule start time by adding the minutes

```
create view movie_schedule_items as
 select CONCAT(p.id, '-', s.id) as id,
   s.id as movie_schedule_id,
   p.id as movie_plan_item_id,
   p.movie_id, p.movie_plan_id,
   (s.start_at + INTERVAL p.start_minutes MINUTE) as start_at,
   (s.start_at + INTERVAL p.end_minutes MINUTE) as end_at
 from movie_plan_items p, movie_schedules s
 where s.movie_plan_id=p.movie_plan_id;
```

I have a model over this view (readonly), it works ok, except that the id is right now a string.

I now want to add a polymorphic property (like comments) to various of the previous tables. Therefore for movie_schedule_items I need a unique and persistent numeric id.

I have the following dilemma:

- I could avoid the id and have movie_schedule_items just use the movie_plan_id and movie_schedule_id as a compound key, as it should. But Rails sucks in this regard.
- I could create an id using String#hash or a md5, thus making it slower or collision prone (and IIRC String#hash is no longer persistent across processes in Ruby 1.9)

Any ideas on how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've built your models a little too complex.
MoviePlan is a pattern that you use for every day's schedule of movies? I'd very much recommend to drop the MovieSchedule and instead allow the user to copy an existing MoviePlan. This will a) make your design simplier and b) allow more freedom for the user as schedules often differ in reality. An extra matinee on Saturdays, a special foreign movie on wednesdays, that's all what I see at my favourite cinema.

Lastly, making comments on a movie of a specific movie plan and schedule doesn't make any sense to me, or is this some customer management thing like "my seat in the 7pm show of Funny Movie was dirty"?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually thought about copying the whole plan data plus the time once it is scheduled. It is an option, yes.

Forget about the comments on the seats. Even the movie thing is just an unreal example that illustrates the core problem (ids on views, so I can have polymorphic associations).

Comment: In that case, easiest is to create a model for MovieScheduleItem, that would also help you to denormalize a few things if necessary for performance.

Comment: That is what I am doing right now. I did not want to, because that model is just the result of adding the minute offsets of the plans to the concrete schedule start time, so I am duplicating data.